# xamarin forms cancel actionsheet programmatically

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, popup

I am presenting an action sheet using following method:

```
var chosenTitle = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", destructiveTitle, titles);
```

Is there any way to programmatically dismiss the action sheet already presented

Comment: Don't think you can do it with the default, but have a look at Acr.UserDialogs

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there isn't. Action sheets are designed for user interaction, not for programmatic interaction. An user can dismiss it by pressing the hardware back button though.

Comment: What if the user press the Home button? It leaves the app in an unstable state if there is a background service. Do you know any solution for this case?